# Calculate and plot statistics on an R matrix

Tags: r, statistics, bioinformatics, data-visualization

My goal is to iterate over a datamatrix, calculate mean, standard error of the mean, and then have a bar plot representing the 2 groups of my data matrix in R.

My code below works as a for loop. However, my initial goal was to output each 8 plots in one .png file. To that end, I posted the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35092812/output-multiple-plots-into-single-file-in-r-within-a-for-loop?noredirect=1#comment58042766_35092812).

One of the 'comments' was to use an 'apply' and 'function'. I never wrote a code in R using apply or function.

Here's my input file:

```
TranscriptID    GeneID  Biotype TranscriptName  CommonNAme  GeneName    TSS-ID  Locus-ID    DNp63D-DMECs-1  DNp63D-DMECs-2  DNp63D-DMECs-3  DNp63WTMECs-1   DNp63WTMECs-2   Fold    2-tailedtest
Test1   TestA   protein_coding  Fun1    Ex1 Ex1 ExA1    ExA1    1.15E-08    2.68E-12    0.005077929 4.99E-07    6.38E-08    6.02E+03    0.495089687
Test2   TestB   protein_coding  Fun2    Ex2 Ex2 ExA2    ExA2    3.69E-08    0.014129129 0.075213367 0.121370367 0.404553833 1.13E-01    0.123434776
Test3   TestC   protein_coding  Fun3    Ex3 Ex3 ExA3    ExA3    4.89E-05    0   0   6.58E-05    1.64E-34    4.96E-01    0.643007583
Test4   TestA   protein_coding  Fun4    Ex4 Ex4 ExA4    ExA4    0.058629449 0   0   0.056200966 0.253314667 1.26E-01    0.180082201
Test5   TestB   protein_coding  Fun5    Ex5 Ex5 ExA5    ExA5    7.80E-06    0   0   1.42E-11    4.20E-36    3.66E+05    0.495026427
Test6   TestC   protein_coding  Fun6    Ex6 Ex6 ExA6    ExA6    0   0   0   0   2.41E-101   0.00E+00    0.272228401
Test7   TestA   protein_coding  Fun7    Ex7 Ex7 ExA7    ExA7    3.77E-08    0.023945749 0.077103517 0.262936167 0.2940195   1.21E-01    0.004479038
Test8   TestB   protein_coding  Fun8    Ex8 Ex8 ExA8    ExA8    9.30E-09    4.82E-14    0.000827853 8.19E-07    7.47E-07    3.52E+02    0.496141526
```

Here is my `for` loop code:

```r
input <- read.delim(file="MECs-DNp63IsoformLevels.txt", header=TRUE, sep="\t")
input<-as.matrix(input)

for (i in 1:nrow(input)) {
mean1 <- mean(as.numeric(input[i,12:13]))
mean2 <- mean(as.numeric(input[i,9:11]))
sd1 <- sd(as.numeric(input[i,12:13]))
sd2 <- sd(as.numeric(input[i,9:11]))
sem1 <- sd2/sqrt(length(input[i,12:13]))
sem2 <- sd1/sqrt(length(input[i,9:11]))

mean_sem <- data.frame(mean=c(mean1, mean2), sem=c(sem1, sem2), group=c("WT", "DNp63D-D")) 
mean_sem$group<-factor(mean_sem$group, levels=mean_sem$group, ordered=TRUE) #this prevents ggplot from ordering the x-axis alphabaetically and keeps the order as the input dataframe
theme_set(theme_gray(base_size = 20))
print(i)
p<- ggplot(mean_sem, aes(x=group, y=mean)) + 
  geom_bar(stat='identity', width=.3, colour="black", fill=c("blue", "red")) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=mean-sem, ymax=mean+sem),
                width=.2) +
  geom_line(aes(colour=group)) +
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("blue", "red")) + 
  xlab('Genotype of MECs') +
  ylab('Quantile Norm FPKM')

q = p +ggtitle(input[i,5])

ggsave(filename=paste(input[i,5],'.png', sep=""), plot=q)

}
```

Here is my code with the apply function:

```r
input <- read.delim(file="MECs-DNp63IsoformLevels.txt", header=TRUE, sep="\t")
input<-as.matrix(input)
apply(input, 1, function(input) { mean1=mean(as.numeric(input[9:11]))                                  
                                   mean2=mean(as.numeric(input[12:13]))
                                   sd1= sd(as.numeric(input[9:11])) 
                                   sd2 = sd(as.numeric(input[12:13]))

                                  sem1= sd1/sqrt(length(input[9:11]))
                                  sem2= sd2/sqrt(length(input[12:13]))                                  

mean_sem = data.frame(mean=c(mean1, sem1), sem=c(sd1, sem2), group=c("WT", "DNp63D-D")) 

pdf("Test.pdf")
p=ggplot(mean_sem, aes(x=group, y=mean))+ geom_bar(stat='identity', width=.3, colour="black", fill=c("blue", "red"))+ geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=mean-sem, ymax=mean+sem), width=.2)+geom_line(aes(colour=group)) + scale_colour_manual(values=c("blue", "red")) + xlab('Genotype of MECs') + ylab('Quantile Norm FPKM')
q = p +ggtitle(input[1])
ggsave(filename=paste(input[1],'.png', sep=""), plot=q) #plots each figure and gives it a name similar to column 1.
## I need it to plot each 8 figures in 1 png file

})
```

Can my `for` loop or function code be optimized? This is literally my first function/apply code I wrote in R and it was more trial and error on the syntax as I saw some people using 'c' with others using multiple `{{}{}` in each function.

Comment: Can you elaborate on `## I need it to plot each 8 figures in 1 png file`? Can you provide 16 lines of data so we see which column can be used to group rows 8 by 8?

Comment: @floder. sure. The way the script above is written, it iterates over each row, then plots one barplot for each for row and outputs each in 1 png file. In fact my data consists of 100's or rows. hence, instead of having 100's of .png files, i was hoping to output 8 plots/png file. I listed an example of the expected outputs [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35092812/output-multiple-plots-into-single-file-in-r-within-a-for-loop?noredirect=1#comment58042766_35092812) . Does this answer your question? Also, do you think my current formatting/write up make sense? Thanks

Comment: It you collect your data into a data.frame instead of plotting in the loop/`*apply`, you can use `facet_wrap` when plotting afterwards, which would likely give you what you're looking for.

Comment: @alistaire can you advise on how to collect it as dataframe? it keeps overwriting.

Comment: If you're in an `*apply` function, you'll have to use `<<-` to break out of its environment so you can append your computations to something; with a `for` loop, you can just use `<-`. Note that pre-allocating a data structure of the correct dimensions can speed up your loop, if necessary. You could probably also refactor your code with `dplyr`, which is usually convenient for these kinds of operations.

Answer (score 1):

This is the first time I have answered anything on SO, and I am not really much of an authority on R or programming in general, so it this may not be optimal, but I thought I'd try and contribute for once.

**Functions**

Firstly I would create a function for the SEM, just because it is handy. I also created a function that wrapped that function and `mean()` to use in `apply()`

```
sem <- function(x){
     sd(x) / sqrt(length(x))
}

sum.stats <- function(x){
     m <- mean(x)
     e <- sem(x)
     c(mean = m, sem = e)
}
```

As you said, the `apply()` function overwrites the previous iterations. I think this is because functions return only the last instruction evaluated, so you have to include everything you want back in a `return()`

**Create df**

I applied `sem()` to each group of data (df1 is the original dataset) separately - you do both groups together as you did above, but this is more general

```
grp.a <- apply(df1[, 12:13], 1, sum.stats)
grp.b <- apply(df1[, 9:11], 1, sum.stats)
```

This produced a dataframe for each group, so these need to be combined for ggplot (Note the reversed expand.grid - by happy accident, I found that this ordered the groups non-alphabetically as you said you wanted)

```
df2 <- data.frame(rev(expand.grid(obs = 1:8, group = c('WT', 'DN'))), 
                  rbind(t(grp.a), t(grp.b)))
```

**Plot**

For the plot, I am not sure about this, but I don't think `apply()` works with `ggplot()` because `ggplot()` needs a dataframe - `apply()` provides a vector.

Also I chose to do away with the legend since the groups are named in the axis labels anyway, and because I think `geom_point()` is more appropriate with those wide error bars - but of course, the choice is yours :)

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df2, aes(group, mean)) +
     geom_point() +
     geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean - sem, ymax = mean + sem), width = 0.2) +
     xlab('Genotype of MECs') + 
     ylab('Quantile Norm FPKM') +
     facet_wrap(~ obs, scales = 'free')

ggsave(filename='plot.png', width = 12, height = 8, units = 'in', dpi = 300)
```

Hope this is useful